# Is there any sqlalchemy list interpolation syntax that works in both sqlite (for test) and mysql (for prod)?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Here is the tiniest example of code that I need to work (we use mysql in prod, we like raw sql queries for complicated queries because the data analysts can read/modify/audit them, we use sqlite for unit testing)

```
    from typing import List, Any

    def test_sqlite_params_demo(self, session):
      session.add(build_foo())
      session.commit()
      query = "select * from foo where id not in :id_list"
      result = session.execute(query, {"id_list": [9, 99, 999]})
      result_dict: List[Any] = [dict(r) for r in result]
      assert len(result_dict) is 1
```

Here is the error that the above causes:

```
        def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "?": syntax error
E       [SQL: select * from patient where id not in ?]
E       [parameters: ([9, 99, 999],)]
E       (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

If I use a tuple instead `result = session.execute(query, {"id_list": (9, 99, 999)})` then the error reads:

```
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "?": syntax error
E       [SQL: select * from foo where id not in ?]
E       [parameters: ((9, 99, 999),)]
E       (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Note: this problem only happens when interpolating a *list* not just a single value

I am using `SQLAlchemy==1.3.11` in my requirements.txt file

Right now I am faced with the unpleasant choice between rewriting the complex code (to a less desirable format) before adding a test, or adding a test which skips/mocks the part of the code that I most want to test. What is a better option?

This question must have been asked before but I haven't been able to find it. Please point me to it if you know where it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an answer that works for me

```
def is_test():
  """
  Tests which want to run code that executes raw sql can override this to be True
  Example:
  @patch('my_app.helpers.raw_sql_runner.is_test', side_effect=lambda: True)
  def test_run_raw_sql_string(self, is_test_mock, session):
  """
  return False

def run_raw_sql(session, sql, params):
  if is_test():
    for key, val in params.items():
        if isinstance(val, (list, tuple)):
            interpolated_sql = sql.replace(f':{key}', f"({','.join(map(str, val))})")
        elif isinstance(val, str):
            interpolated_sql = sql.replace(f':{key}', f"'{str(val)}'")
        else:
            interpolated_sql = sql.replace(f':{key}', str(val))
    return session.execute(interpolated_sql, params)
  else:
    return session.execute(sql, params)
```

I also needed to create some methods that mysql has that sqlite does not have.

```
# conftest.py
def fake_sqlite_concat(a, b):
  return f'{a}{b}'

def create_sqlite_functions(con):
  con.create_function("concat", 2, fake_sqlite_concat)
  # more functions go here as needed

con = engine.connect().connection
create_sqlite_functions(con)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cast your query to a `sqlalchemy.text` object, that should work.

```py
from sqlalchemy import text
result = session.execute(text(query), {"id_list": [9, 99, 999]})
```

Comment: This solution does not change the error message that I am seeing. :( What version of sqlalchemy are you using? I have `SQLAlchemy==1.3.11`